# How do I install gnu sc on my mac?

Tags: command-line, install, unix, homebrew

I want to install the command line spreadsheet sc.  I would prefer to do with homebrew.  I need both psc and sc commands.  Is there a homebrew package?  If not other methods would be good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your wish is my command!

Homebrew Formula: [sc.rb](https://gist.github.com/geoff-codes/d8c16ada1de10e6387b3)

I'll try to get the formula merged into homebrew proper sometime this week.

In the meantime, you can simply:

`brew install https://gist.github.com/geoff-codes/d8c16ada1de10e6387b3/raw/sc.rb`

Comment: Well done.  Please do go through the merge process.

Comment: I'd love to see your formula integrated into homebrew - I couldn't find it there as of yet.

Answer (score 3):

For all true fans of terminal-based editing, there are two basic chains to follow, all based on the so far last known original source [Version 7.16 at ibiblio](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/apps/financial/spreadsheet/). The file you want is: sc-7.16.tar.gz

1. [sc-im](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im), an improved version of sc, adding undo, sorting, filtering, subtotals, cell shifting and gnuplot graphics among other features while still remaining true to its origin. Can be installed following the instructions at its [github-repository](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im). Highly recommended!
2. "pure" sc, which can be installed either directly, via Homebrew (several unofficial integrations, none of which merged into upstream yet), or through MacPorts.

   - [Version 7.16 at ibiblio](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/apps/financial/spreadsheet/), or via [dkastner's tracking repository](https://github.com/dkastner/sc) at github.
   - Using a [Debianized version](https://github.com/hermo/homebrew-sc), calling itself 7.16-3 [(version summary)](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/sc.git/). Homebrew install via: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hermo/homebrew-sc/master/Formula/sc.rb`
   - Using [Geoff's excellent integration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231855/18536), which is installing version 7.16 and applying patches added to the Ubuntu repository, resulting in a version 7.16-4 [(Version history)](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/sc/wily/changes): `brew install https://gist.github.com/geoff-codes/d8c16ada1de10e6387b3/raw/sc.rb`
   - From [homebrew-alt](http://ps://github.com/zpao/homebrew-alt) (Link no longer functioning as of 2017-12-29), which uses [Version 7.16 from ibiblio](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/apps/financial/spreadsheet/), applying patches to the Makefile to improve handling of the Homebrew directory structure: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zpao/homebrew-alt/master/other/sc.rb`
   - Via MacPorts, if that's your ecosystem, as [described by Mateusz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231645/18536)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it via [Macports](https://www.macports.org)

After you install Macports you can get `sc` with:

```
port install sc
```

(You might need `sudo` for this)

Here's the sc profile:
https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/finance/sc/Portfile